# iPadOS 13.x PIP mode not working with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm using `AVPlayerViewController` to play a video on an iPad running 13.3. However, I do not want the on-screen controls, so I set `showsPlaybackControls` to `false` before presenting the controller.

I noticed that when `showsPlaybackControls` is set to `false`, picture-in-picture does (by pressing the home button or swiping up from the bottom) not work on iPads running 13.3. Everything works fine on 12.4. This is reproducible with a basic `AVPlayerViewController` app running on the simulator.

Does anyone know if this the expected behavior? Or is there is another way to get the behavior I want?

Comment: I presume what you mean is: We start play in some other way, the user hits the Home button, and we should go into picture-in-picture mode automatically, and we don't is `showsPlaybackControls` is `false`. I see the same thing, but I don't know if it's "expected" or not.